# How to Manipulate JQuery .get() response

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Using a suggestion found at http://richardmiller.co.uk/2011/03/04/jquery-manipulating-ajax-response-before-inserting-into-the-dom/ to be able to manipulate my data response from a JQuery `.get()` method, I'm unable to actually make any changes to the object.

**JavaScript**

```
$.get( "returnAjax", function( data ) {
    var $data = $(data);
    $data.find('#testdiv').append('<p>Some Text</p>');
    console.log($data);
});
```

**PHP**

```
public function returnAjax()
{
    return "<div id='testdiv'></div>";

}
```

The output in the console is simply `<div id="testdiv"></div>`

This seems like the most simple thing but I'm not doing something right...

Comment: Tried `$data.append('<p>Some Text</p>');` ? `$data` appear to be `#testdiv` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

> Get the descendants of each element in the current set of matched
>   elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element.

which traverses `$data` descendants for `#testdiv` , where `$data` appear to be `#testdiv` element itself ?

Try

`$data.append('<p>Some Text</p>');console.log($data.is("#testdiv"))`

Comment: ahh gotcha.  of course the actual use was much more complicated, but I was still trying to perform the action on the "parent" element.  I simply removed `.find()` and performed the necessary action on `$data` itself and it worked perfect

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps double wrap the testdiv finding query:

```
$.get( "returnAjax", function( data ) {
    var $data = $(data);
    $($data.find('#testdiv')).append('<p>Some Text</p>');
    console.log($data);
});
```